# iterator declaration with VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, iterator

I'm trying to declaration AN iterator, but I having problem with it. 
I'm using VC++2010

```
#include<iterator> 
#include<map>
using namespace std;
using std::regex_replace;
template <class KTy, class Ty>
void PrintMap(map<KTy, Ty> map)
{
   **:iterator iterator;
      for (iterator p = map.begin(); p != map.end(); p++)
    cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;** 
}
```

The error message is:

> Error 1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'( for :iterator iterator;)

Comment: Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ':'( for :iterator iterator;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that you have named your variable **map** which is a type name.

```
void PrintMap(map<KTy, Ty> map)
{
   **:iterator iterator;
      for (iterator p = map.begin(); p != map.end(); p++)
    cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;** 
}
```

Do this instead...

```
template <typename KTy, typename Ty>
void PrintMap(map<KTy, Ty> mymap)
{   
    typedef typename map<KTy, Ty>::iterator iterator;       
    for (iterator p = mymap.begin(); p != mymap.end(); p++)
        cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you want to change the name of your parameter to something other than `map`, that's ambiguous since it's also a type name.

Assuming you want a `typedef` for the iterator type, use:

```
typedef typename map<KTy, Ty>::iterator iterator;

for (iterator p = my_map.begin(); p != my_map.end(); p++) {
    cout << p->first << ": " << p->second << endl;
}
```

Note: you need the `typename` keyword because the type is dependent on a template parameter.

Comment: @user27995: Oh hey, change the name of the parameter to something other than `map`. You also have a type of the same name.